# Getting data from a fmt::Arguments without heap allocation

Tags: rust, format, rust-no-std

I want to make `write!` work on my own struct implementing `fmt::Write`, and I don't have any heap allocation. To do so, I'd need to implement `fmt::Write::write_fmt(&mut self, args: fmt::Arguments<'_>) -> fmt::Result`

However, this means that I need to access the data in a `fmt::Arguments<'_>` without using `&args.to_string()`, as `.to_string()` does not exist without heap allocation.

There is [`Arguments::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html#impl), however it doesn't work as soon as I need to format elements as `i32`.

Is there a way to get the arguments' strings without using `.to_string()` ?

Comment: Implementing the `write_fmt` method is not required, and the default implementation doesn't do any heap allocation AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Arguments<'_>` contains a pre-parsed argument string and the arguments passed with it. You cannot break it up or mess around with the internals because that would be unsafe, so the only reasonable things you *can* do with it are:

- pass it to [`core::fmt::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/fn.write.html) (or `std::fmt::format`, but that returns a `String`)
- or pass it to one of the formatting macros (e.g. `write!`) along with a `"{}"` or `"{:?}"` format string.

The second option doesn't work in your case because you're implementing `write_fmt`, and `write!` calls `write_fmt`, so this would likely lead to infinite recursion. But you can still just call `write(&mut self, args)`. [`write`'s implementation only uses `write_str`, not `write_fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#1104-1140).

In fact, the [provided implementation of `Write::write_fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#186-188) does exactly this:

```
fn write_fmt(mut self: &mut Self, args: Arguments<'_>) -> Result {
    write(&mut self, args)
}
```

Since this already exists, and there's no reasonable alternative implementation, you probably should not override `write_fmt` at all unless you have *very* specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks. At first, I didn''t implement `write_fmt`, as I read it was given once we implemented `write_str`. However, this caused my code to crash, and by implementing `write_fmt` such that it does nothing, my code ran. I don't know why so I assumed it had something with heap allocation, but apparently not. With your code at least, I'll be able to debug, thanks !